# Переименование дублирующихся узлов TreeView по порядку

Tags: xml, treeview, delphi-xe

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть вот такой TreeView:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я никак не могу понять как мне сделать так, чтобы с самого начала пройтись по всем элементам TreeView и если есть дубликаты как в примере (rst:ShopPosition) то с начала их пронумеровать, в конце элемента добавив к нему [0],[1],[2] и т.д.?

Почему-то у меня функция всегда переходит к следующему элементу по списку, а не к следующему элементу родителя.

```
procedure TForm1.NumberContent(nodes: TTreeView);
var i: integer;
    ANode: TTreeNode;
begin
  for I := 0 to nodes.Items.Count-1 do
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(nodes.Item[i].Text);
  end;
end;
```